# Y-tick labels disappear if I run full Python script (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I'm using Spyder (python 2.7), and plotting graphs using matplotlib. When I have a chunk of code (see below), everything looks fine if I highlight and execute my code manually. However, if I hit the run button for the full script, or execute this code within a loop, the y-tick labels disappear from each plot. Can't for the life of me find the problem.

```
data2plot = [120.0, 56.0, 26.0, 11.0, 6.0, 6.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
bar_locs = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0]
x_labs = ['','','','','','','','','','','','','']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#plot_help.bigfig()    
rects = ax.bar(bar_locs, data2plot, 0.75, color='steelblue', align='center')                 
ax.set_xticks(bar_locs)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labs, fontweight='bold', fontsize=13, rotation=-45, ha='left')      
ax.set_xlim(0, len(x_labs)+0.75)
#ax.set_ylim(0, y_max)
ax.set_ylabel('Pageviews', fontweight='bold', fontsize=15)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontweight='bold', fontsize=13)
ax.set_title('Title', fontweight='bold', fontsize=16)    

plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.45)
#plot_help.simpleaxis(ax)
```

Comment: You should not post the code that works. But instead post the code that gives an error.

Comment: If I hit "run" on this script, then this code does give an "error" in the sense that the graph will have no y-tick labels.

Comment: Noone can verify that, because we do not have your variables. If you're interested in getting an answer, you should provide a [MCVE].

Comment: my bad. i updated the original post.

Comment: Just to be clear: if I highlight and run just this chunk of code, everything is fine. However, if I hit the run file button, or highlight and run code like this within a loop to make multiple graphs, the y-tick labels disappear.

Comment: @pavlov You need to post code that we can run to see the problem. Also get rid of everything which is not necessary. Can't you reproduce the issue without setting subplot params, titles, font attributes, color, alignment, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is in this line   `ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), ...)`.
In the moment you call `ax.get_yticklabels()` the ticklabels have not yet been set, so `ax.get_yticklabels()` returns a list of empty strings. Those empty strings are then set as new yticklabels. 
You can prevent this from happening if you call `fig.canvas.draw()` beforehands. This will draw the figure and initialize the ticklabels such that the list will not be empty strings when given to the setter.

Here is the complete code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data2plot = [120.0, 56.0, 26.0, 11.0, 6.0, 6.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
bar_locs = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0]
x_labs = ['','','','','','','','','','','','','']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()   
rects = ax.bar(bar_locs, data2plot, 0.75, color='steelblue', align='center')

# x-axis              
ax.set_xticks(bar_locs)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labs, fontweight='bold', fontsize=13, rotation=-45, ha='left')      
ax.set_xlim(0, len(x_labs)+0.75)

#y-axis
ax.set_ylabel('Pageviews', fontweight='bold', fontsize=15)
fig.canvas.draw()
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontweight='bold', fontsize=13)


ax.set_title('Title', fontweight='bold', fontsize=16)    
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.45)
plt.show()
```

---

Alternatively, if your intention is to get all the text, labels and titles in the figure bold and bigger, then you might consider using the [matplotlib rcParams](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) as follows.

```
plt.rc('font', size=13, weight='bold')
plt.rc('figure', titlesize="x-large", titleweight ='bold')
plt.rc("axes", labelsize = "large", labelweight = "bold", titlesize="x-large", titleweight="bold")

data2plot = [120.0, 56.0, 26.0, 11.0, 6.0, 6.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
bar_locs = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0]
x_labs = ['','','','','','','','','','','','','']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()   
rects = ax.bar(bar_locs, data2plot, 0.75, color='steelblue', align='center')

# x-axis              
ax.set_xticks(bar_locs)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labs, rotation=-45, ha='left')      
ax.set_xlim(0, len(x_labs)+0.75)

#y-axis
ax.set_ylabel('Pageviews')

ax.set_title('Title')    
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.45)
plt.show()
```